# Where can I view Nightly's Changelog?

Tags: firefox

Where can I find out what changes were made in Nightly? It is updated so much so I would like to know what changes I should expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Where can I find out what changes were made in Nightly?

Look at the [pushlog](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml?startdate=48+hours+ago&enddate=now).

Example:

[image]